# Unable to connect to On Prem Kafka topic from GCP

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am trying to consume a kafka topic using SASL but getting an Error which has no documentation :

```
ERROR:kafka.conn:Connect attempt to <BrokerConnection node_id=<nodeid> host=<bootstrapserver>:9094 <connecting> [IPv4 ('<IPAddress>', 9094)]> returned error 110. Disconnecting.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We need to see your `advertised.listeners`  setting on your brokers and you can use kcat command to verify it works https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @OneCricketeer I dont have access to it, we only have the consumer. What exactly goes into advertised.listeneres? The ip:port of the consumer VM?

Comment: No. It's the address that your consumer must connect to. If your on prem firewall doesn't allow connections from GCP, it'll fail. If you don't advertise Kafka over the internet, it'll fail... We also need to see what SASL properties exist in your code and broker.